# LINQ number of database calls

Tags: linq

If I have code like below is the database being called twice for the `Any` and the `Where`?

```
if (context.SomeTable.Any(x => x.SomeValue == "A"))
    var result = context.SomeTable.Where(x => x.SomeValue == "A")
```

Comment: You can use profiler and see it in action ;)

Comment: Yes. You should just call it once with `Where` and then check if any results were returned.

Comment: Isn't it possible to combine these two queries? Google for LINQ Examples. and use LINQ Pad to visualize your query

Comment: I know it possible to combine the queries. It's something I keeps seeing in code someone else has written and was wondering if it needs fixing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I would expect it to be.

Quite how you want to handle that will depend on the context. For example, you might want:

```
var result = context.SomeTable
                    .Where(x => x.SomeValue == "A")
                    .Take(10)
                    .ToList();
if (result.Count == 0)
{
    // Indicate that there were no results
}
else
{
    // Use it somehow
}
```

But of course that is deliberately written to limit how many records are returned, and it materializes the result. If you don't know which path you're going to take until you've found out how many records there are, and you don't want to load the data into memory *at that point* then it becomes trickier.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would be called twice. Also there is no sense in doing such check - if there is data, you anyway should load them.

**NOTE** Actually your code executes only one `Any` query. Second query is only defined here and will be executed when you will try to get it's results.